# RNN model for predicting sequences based on sequences of different lengths with Keras

Tags: python, classification, keras, lstm

I have data that are sequences of repeated values of different lengths. The value is **categorical** and can take values from 1 to 184. I used padded with 0 and masking:

```
[[1, 1, 2, ... 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 6, 1, ... 0, 0, 0],
 ...
 [4, 4, 3, ... 0, 0, 0]]
```

With that code:

```
padded_inputs = tf.keras.utils.pad_sequences(train['Data'], padding="post")
embedding = layers.Embedding(input_dim=10000, output_dim=16, mask_zero=True)
X_train = embedding(padded_inputs)
```

My **target** - `y_train` that I need to predict is a sequence of the same categorical repeating values with length 10:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 1, 6, 2, 2],
[2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 7, 1],
...
[6, 9, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2]]
```

I created a simple LSTM model using Keras:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(None, 16))) 
model.add(Dense(10, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

batch_size = 32
epochs = 10
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size)

preds_train = model.predict(X_train)
```

But the model gives a prediction like:

```
[[0.88863385, 0.74388796, 0.8497969 , 0.82645077, 0.55977786, 0.7694494 , 0.8115073 , 0.5448062 , 0.510332  , 0.77190804],
[0.88863385, 0.743888  , 0.8497969 , 0.82645077, 0.5597778, 0.7694494 , 0.8115073 , 0.5448062 , 0.510332  , 0.77190804],
...
[0.88863385, 0.743888  , 0.8497969 , 0.82645077, 0.55977786, 0.7694495 , 0.8115073 , 0.5448062 , 0.510332  , 0.77190804]]
```

And I need a prediction in format like my target with my categorical values. How can i do that?